# Migration again after copy db from my host in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I tried to copy my db from the server host with its rows and all data. after I did it, I tried to migrate my code first, the migration created another table with the same names as you see in this image

so can anyone explain what happened and why created another table? and how I use my old columns with their data.

I sought to migrate with an empty up/down migration file

[image]

this is my local connection string

**`Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=gasdwa7d;Integrated Security=True`**

and my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDbConnection"));
            options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
        });

        

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
            , ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
        services.AddSignalR();

        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.220"));
        });

        services.Configure<TwilioVerifySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("Twilio"));

        //JWT Generate Token

        var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(appSettingsSection);

        var appSettings = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSettings>();
        var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(appSettings.Secret);
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });

        // configure DI for application services
        services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
        {
            ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/ChatHub");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What problem are you facing?

Comment: why it create another tables

Comment: i edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have different schema names as you can see in the picture provided.

You specify a different schema name in the ModelBuilder of ef core 3. You can do it by using `modelBuilder.ToTable("Table_Name", "Schema_Name");`, or you can do it with a Data Annotation.

Either way you can read this article on Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-schema

or you specify the default Schema for all models which is what I suggest you do.

```
public class SchoolContext: DbContext 
{
    public SchoolDBContext(): base() 
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Standard> Standards { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure default schema
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Admin");
    }
}
```

More on that here:
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx